# Testing a variable scope association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I'm trying to make my tests robust and really solid, and I've been breaking down some complex queries and associations into smaller ones, or refactoring and moving the data into scopes.

Given the following classes:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location

  scope :in_location, ->(location) { where(location: location) }
  scope :findable,    ->(location, not_ids) {
    in_location(location).where.not(id: not_ids)
  }
end

class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  # THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO TEST 
  has_many :findable_items, ->(container) { 
    findable(container.location, container.not_findable_ids)
  }, class_name: 'Item'
end
```

How would you test a variable has_many relationship like this without hitting the database to a significant degree? I know I can test the Item.findable method on it's own; what I'm interested in is the container.findable_items method.

**Note**: the actual association being tested is more complex than this, and would require pretty extensive set-up; it's running through a few other nested associations and scopes. I'd like to avoid this setup if possible, and just test that the scope is called with the correct values.

Relevant parts of my Gemfile:

```
rails (4.2.3)
shoulda-matchers (2.6.2)
factory_girl (4.5.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
rspec-core (3.3.2)
rspec-expectations (3.3.1)
rspec-its (1.2.0)
rspec-mocks (3.3.2)
rspec-rails (3.3.3)
```

I have shoulda-matchers in my project, so I can do the basic sanity test:

```
it { should have_many(:findable_items).class_name('Item') }
```

but this fails:

```
describe 'findable_line_items' do
  let(:container) { @container } # where container is a valid but unsaved Container
  let(:location)  { @container.location }
  it 'gets items that are in the location and not excluded' do
    container.not_findable_ids = [1,2]
    # so it doesn't hit the database
    expect(Item).to receive(:findable).with(location, container.not_findable_ids) 
    container.findable_items
  end
end
```

This spec fails with the following error:

```
1) Container findable_line_items gets items that are in the location and not excluded
 Failure/Error: container.findable_items
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `except' for nil:NilClass
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:158:in `block (2 levels) in add_constraints'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:154:in `each'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:154:in `block in add_constraints'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:141:in `each'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:141:in `each_with_index'
 # /[redacted]/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:141:in `add_constraints'
 # /[redacted]/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:39:in `scope'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:5:in `scope'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:97:in `association_scope'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:86:in `scope'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:423:in `scope'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:37:in `initialize'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:106:in `new'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:106:in `create'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:39:in `reader'
 # /[redacted]/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:115:in `pickable_items'
 # ./spec/models/container_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How would you get this spec to pass, without actually setting up an Item that meets all the requirements?

Comment: Stubbing out the database is in many cases a good idea but not here since both scopes and relations in rails are intricately tied to the ORM / db. Even if it is possible what value would your test actually give if you are stubbing the actual functionality?

Comment: I'm testing the 'actual' functionality in a test in the item_spec; I don't need to test that the scope works here, just that it's being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a solution like this:

```
describe 'findable_line_items' do
  let(:container) { @container } # where container is a valid but unsaved Container
  let(:location)  { @container.location }
  it 'gets items that are in the location and not excluded' do
    # so it doesn't hit the database
    expect(Item).to receive(:findable).with(location, container.not_findable_ids).and_call_original
    expect(container).to receive(:location).and_call_original
    expect(container).to receive(:not_findable_ids).and_call_original
    container.findable_items
  end
end
```

The error that was occurring was somewhere in the ActiveRecord association setup; it was trying to instantiate an ActiveRecord array on a `nil` object which was being returned from my Item stub. Adding `.and_call_original` solved that error.

I don't really care to test that the correct objects are being returned from this association, since that scope is being tested elsewhere, just that the scope is being used. It still hits the database in this scenario, but not the 15 times that would be required to set up a full test.